# Boolean does not get set on the right moment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, boolean

I have a `BOOL loginStatus` that I am going to use in a login flow.

---

### Code

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    if ([self credentialsValidated]) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
     }else {
       NSLog(@"not valid");
     }
}

- (BOOL)credentialsValidated {
     [[API sharedInstance] loginCommand:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtLogin.text,@"email",_txtPass.text,@"pwd", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
     //completion
         if(![json objectForKey:@"error"]){
             if([[json valueForKeyPath:@"data.status"]intValue] == 200){
                //Create user object
                 NSLog(@"tot hier");
                loginstatus =  YES;
             }else{
                 //show validation
                 NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json valueForKeyPath:@"data.text"]];
                 [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Fout" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                 _txtLogin.text = @"";
                 _txtPass.text = @"";
                 loginstatus = NO;
             }
         }else {
             NSLog(@"Cannot connect to the server");
         }
     }];
     if(loginstatus){
         NSLog(@"true");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"false");
    }
     return loginstatus;
}
```

---

The problem I have is that my `BOOL` is not set immediately. I always need to press two times the login button before my boolean is set correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: when did you initialize the boolean value first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Boolean isn't set immediately because it is being set in the completion block, which isn't called until the asynchronous operation completes. You should do something to allow the user to wait while the API works.

For example, you could disable the fields and display a spinning progress indicator until the login operation completes. You would configure the UI to be disabled before the call to login and set it back to enabled in the completion block.

Comment: The code highly depends on your UI design, so we aren't able to provide you the specifics. If you want a short-term solution, consider using the API's synchronous methods, if it has synchronous methods.

Failing that, you can always use an NSLock or GCD mutex to have the main thread wait until the completion block is executed.

Comment: I'm very new to this. I am using the AFNetworking library to do my calls.

Comment: AFNetworking objects inherit from NSOperation. All you should have to do is call waitUntilFinished on the AF request operation after you call start to have the current thread wait until the operation is complete.